# how to get url browser by Acceesibility (Class Name)

Tags: android

I want to get browsers Url using **AcceesibilityService**. I use EditText className in chrome and TextView className in Firefox. It works in all devices but does't work in Redmi xiaomi devices. In Redmi xiaomi devices parentNodeInfo className  does't return EditText or TextView. Someone can help?

Here is my code :

```
if (eventValue == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED) {
            CharSequence className = parentNodeInfo.getClassName();

            if (className.equals("android.widget.EditText") || className.equals("android.widget.TextView")) {
                synchronized (Utils.isWorkingUrl) {
                    CharSequence strUrl = parentNodeInfo.getText();
                    if (strUrl != null) {

                        boolean isActiveUrlLog = SharedPref.read_Bool(getApplicationContext(), SharedPref.PREFKEY, SharedPref.IS_ACTIVE_URL_LOG);
                        if (isActiveUrlLog) {

                          boolean isUrl = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(strUrl).matches();

                           if (isUrl) {

                                boolean isConnected = ConnectionInternet.checkConnection();
                                if (isConnected) {
                                    if ( Utils.pskIsBrowser(packageNameCurrent,this,true)){

                                        if (!strUrl.equals("www.")){
                                            strUrl="https://www." + strUrl;
                                            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                                            ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
                                            imageLoader.LoadImage(Utils.getUtilsString(getApplicationContext(), UtilsText.DOMAIN_LOAD_ICON_URl) + "?sz=64&domain_url=" + strUrl, imageView, R.drawable.globe, false, sqlpc);
                                            lastTime = currentTime;
                                        }
                                        else if (!strUrl.equals("https://")){
                                            strUrl="https://" +strUrl;
                                            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                                            ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
                                            imageLoader.LoadImage(Utils.getUtilsString(getApplicationContext(), UtilsText.DOMAIN_LOAD_ICON_URl) + "?sz=64&domain_url=" + strUrl, imageView, R.drawable.globe, false, sqlpc);
                                            lastTime = currentTime;
                                        }else {
                                            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                                            ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
                                            imageLoader.LoadImage(Utils.getUtilsString(getApplicationContext(), UtilsText.DOMAIN_LOAD_ICON_URl) + "?sz=64&domain_url=" + strUrl, imageView, R.drawable.globe, false, sqlpc);
                                            lastTime = currentTime;
                                        }
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead , U can use browser view id , here is my [code](https://github.com/javadssmsh/Accessibility-Service/blob/main/app/src/main/java/ir/javadsh/challenge/service/TextAccessibilityService.java) .

```
        String packageName = event.getPackageName().toString();
    SupportedBrowserConfig browserConfig = null;
    for (SupportedBrowserConfig supportedConfig : getSupportedBrowsers()) {
        if (supportedConfig.packageName.equals(packageName)) {
            browserConfig = supportedConfig;
        }
    }
    //this is not supported browser, so exit
    if (browserConfig == null) {
        return;
    }

    String requiredText = "";
    if (parentNodeInfo.getText() != null) {
        requiredText = parentNodeInfo.getText().toString();
    }
    String capturedUrl = captureUrl(parentNodeInfo, browserConfig);
    parentNodeInfo.recycle();


@NonNull
private static String[] packageNames() {
    List<String> packageNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (SupportedBrowserConfig config : getSupportedBrowsers()) {
        packageNames.add(config.packageName);
    }
    return packageNames.toArray(new String[0]);
}

private static class SupportedBrowserConfig {
    public String packageName, addressBarId;

    public SupportedBrowserConfig(String packageName, String addressBarId) {
        this.packageName = packageName;
        this.addressBarId = addressBarId;
    }
}


@NonNull
private static List<SupportedBrowserConfig> getSupportedBrowsers() {
    List<SupportedBrowserConfig> browsers = new ArrayList<>();
    browsers.add(new SupportedBrowserConfig("com.android.chrome", "com.android.chrome:id/url_bar"));
    browsers.add(new SupportedBrowserConfig("org.mozilla.firefox", "org.mozilla.firefox:id/url_bar_title"));
    return browsers;
}


enter code here
```